# Explicit bijection from distinct unordered pairs of integers to the integers form $1$ to $n$ choose $2$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

I am looking for an explicit (where I leave the meaning of this up to you) function $f$ that gives a bijection between distinct unordered pairs of integers $\{ i , j \}$ with $1 \leq i,j \leq n$ and the set of integers $k$ with $1 \leq k \leq \frac{n(n - 1)}{2}$.

For example, for $n = 3$, $f(\{ i, j\} ) = i + j - 2$ is an example of such a function, however this is no longer bijective for $n = 4$.

Comment: Your title says ordered, but your question says unordered. Which one is it? I think it is unordered.

Comment: For $i<j$ you can choose $1+\binom{j-1}2+\binom{i-1}1.$ This generalizes to $r$-subsets with $i_1<i_2<\dots<i_r$ getting index:$$1+\sum_{j=1}^r \binom{i_j-1}{j}$$ and corresponds to the index of the so-called 'squashed order." It actually works for all $r$-subsetts of $\mathbb N^+,$ with the first $\binom nr$ being the subsets with maximum element $\leq n.$ (The formula becomes slightly nicer if we choose $0\leq i,j\<n$ and indices $0\leq k<\binom nr.$ Then we can lose the $-1$s and $+1$s in the formula.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Sorry unordered - thank you for the correction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a mapping which works, taken a comment  by Thomas Andrews.

$$
\{i,j\}\mapsto 1 + \binom{\min(i,j)-1}1+\binom{\max(i,j)-1}2
$$

This is [combinadics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system), in the case of sets of size $2$. See the linked Wikipedia article for details on why this is a bijection.

Here is an illustration of the bijection when $n=5$.

| i | j | output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 | 6 |
| 1 | 5 | 7 |
| 2 | 5 | 8 |
| 3 | 5 | 9 |
| 4 | 5 | 10 |